# How can I get bracket pair colorization for Visual Studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

recently I switched a project from VSC to VS and I am quite unhappy with how the highlighting in VS works.

In VSC with the "Python" Extension published by microsoft, my code looks like this:

[Highlighting in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feUf0.png)

in VS it looks like this:

[Highlighting in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXvk7.png)

As an example it is nice to have different colors for the brackets so you can instantly see which level you're on. In VS this seems to be missing and I want to know if there is a way to enable the highlighting to look similar to the one in VSC.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: There are extensions that support brace colorization for sure. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/adding-color-to-bracket-pairs/

Answer (score 0):

**Tools - Options - Environment - Fonts and Colors - Operator**

You can set the color by clicking item foreground.

[image]